# WPF : How to scroll a ListView control horizontal?

Tags: wpf, listview

I manually need to scroll the content of a ListView control to the left side.

It is invoked automatically when I call *scrollIntoView* but only if the item to scroll to is not visible. The ListView will scroll to the item and scroll horizontal to the left side. Just like I need it to be.

But if the item to scroll to is already visible nothing will happen and that is the reason I need to scroll left manually.

Comment: If the item is already visible, what autoscroll would have to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find the `ScrollViewer` for the `ListView` by traversing the Visual Tree and then call `ScrollToLeftEnd`. Something like this should work

```
private void ScrollListViewToLeft(ListView listView)
{
    ScrollViewer listViewScrollViewer = GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(listView);
    listViewScrollViewer.ScrollToLeftEnd();
}
private static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```